# Oracle Pro C config reload

Tags: sql, linux, oracle

ORACLE PRO C precomp

I changed the value of sys_include in my pcscfg.cfg, but when I do

proc sys_include = ?

, I see the old value.
How do I overload the value of the variable sys_include?

Thx

Comment: Are you sure you changed the same file that your help command reports against "System default option values taken from:" ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Does Pro C load this file every time it is called or can I somehow reload it?

Comment: It loads it every time, which is why I was asking. If I change the file then the change is immediately reflected by the command you used. (This is Pro\*C from 12.1.0.2 instant client on Linux x64 but not sure that should mater).